# Is there a way to have a stacked sparkline widgetColumn in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, bar-chart, sparklines, extjs-grid, extjs-chart

Ext.js has the `Ext.sparkline.Bar` class. Is it possible to make that bar chart stacked? I have implemented a `cartesian` as the widget for the widget column to achieve this effect, But it has led to very long load times (particularly when calling grid.reconfigure()). I'm wondering if a more lightweight version can be achieved via a sparkline.

The reason I'm thinking it may be possible is because of the `stackedBarColor` config in the `Ext.sparkline.Bar` class. Aside from that, I haven't been able to find anything in regards to implementing it.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for `Ext.sparkline.Bar`, do a CTRL+F, type: 'stacked'. You can follow the logic there. at the most basic level you can achieve a stacked bar chart by passing in an array of arrays into the values config: `values: [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]`. Each array will be its own stack.